# grafana, invalidate data/ inhibit interpolation on timeout

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have an Influxdb / Grafana setup  where I typically store and display some equidistantly sampled data.

Now I want to inhibit the interpolation of the graph when the typical sample time is violated.

So lets say, I get new data every 10 sec, but when some of the sensors loses connection, and reconnects after one minute, I have a gap in the data.
I want to be aware about this gap, in best way by simply not displaying something between these time-frame violating points.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, working now.

I didn't understand that these kind of problem is basically solved by Influxdb and its Query api.

I had to change my query from

SELECT value FROM "temperature"

(which is the level of database api I could understand) to

SELECT mean("value") FROM "temperature" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)

and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Under the display tab in the graph panel you can change `Null value` to null as zero.

You also have to change the `fill` parameter in the metrics query's group by to `null`